# .htaccess rewritecond match something except

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get my .htaccess file to work. Well it already works, but something is a bit annoying right now.

I have modyfied my .htaccess to support multi-language website with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/[a-z]{2}/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

# match those that DO have a language code
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [PT,L]
```

This works like a charm. When a two-char language code is added to the beginning of the URL the ?lang is added to my index.php. However this is a problem because my javascript folder is called "js" which means this will treated as if it was a language code. I actually thought that the two first RewriteCond's would prevent this from happening, but apparently it isn't.

I must admit that the .htaccess isn't what I'm best at so I might have missed some sort of simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1:** Use this rule (instead of your last line):

```
RewriteRule ^(?!js)([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [PT,L]
```

This will do nothing for `/js/hello` but will rewrite if `/en/hello` (for example) requested.

**Option #2:** Add condition similar to what you have for previous rule (I assume `/public/js/` is the actual folder for your JavaScript files -- if not, adjust the name accordignly):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [PT,L]
```

I recommend #1 -- it's may be more difficult to understand .. but it's all in single line and a bit faster (single regex versus two in #2).